# Maze Algorithm KINDA works. Some mazes, not ALL help

Tags: java, recursion, solver, maze

I am using a maze algorithm that works some of the time, but not all of the time. It uses recursion but I cannot figure out why it doesnt all the time.

```
public boolean findPath(int x, int y) {
    myArray[x][y] = "T";    // marks coordinate T for traveled
    printMaze();  // prints the current state of the maze

    if (x == finish[0] && y == finish[1]) { // base case: if at finish, solved.
        isFinish = true;
        return isFinish;
    } else {
        isFinish = false;                   // not at finish
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (i * j == 0 && i != j && canIGoHere(x+i, y+j) && !isFinish) {
                    isFinish = findPath(x + i, y + j);
                }
            }
        }
        return isFinish;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might start by adding proper identation It may be good for you, but most of us ( at least my self ) are not used to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function should return as soon as isFinish is true. As it is now, the function may find the finish position but it then continues to loop and may move away from that position before returning.